# making a search with JS

Tags: javascript

i want to make Search but i have a problem. It shows me  "The CurentElement is not defined"... Can you help me

```
$("#searchForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let matches = [ ];
    let searchText = $("#searchText").val();
    for (let i = 0; i < products.lenght; i++) {
        let currentProduct = products[i];
        let nameTolower = currentProduct.name.toLowerCase();
        let isMatch = nameToLower.indexOf(searchText) >= 0;
        if(isMatch){
            matches.push(currentProduct)
         };
    };
        appendProducts(matches);

});
```

Comment: where is `CurentElement ` in your code?

Comment: `products.length` line 5.

Comment: note that there is also a (common) typing error here: `lenght` should be `length`. You should maybe add the code where `products` is set, we can't guess.

Comment: How can upload full code to see it ?

Comment: Just add the code that is needed to trigger the problem, not everything. Additionally, please share the full and exact error message and the line triggering it

Comment: problem in code is in this which is uploaded :(

Answer (score 0):

Two quick fix if I may first, it's `products.length` and not `products.lenght` and just after you instancy this variable `nameTolower` but you call `nameToLower` this one after, there's a caps on the 'L' :)

I assume your products is an array of objects because of these two lines :

```
let currentProduct = products[i];
let nameTolower = currentProduct.name.toLowerCase();
```

So I'm emptying results  tag, then I see with your function if the name match and then I append the datas.
And if you submit while the input is empty, it will show all the products.

```js
const products = [
  {name: "First", price: 25, quantity: 5}, 
  {name: "Second", price: 10, quantity: 3}
];

$("#searchForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Empty HTML tag first
    $('#results').empty();
    let matches = [];
    let searchText = $("#searchText").val().toLowerCase(); // toLowerCase() because you're checking nameToLower just after
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        let currentProduct = products[i];
        let nameToLower = currentProduct.name.toLowerCase();
        let isMatch = nameToLower.indexOf(searchText) >= 0;
        if(isMatch){
            matches.push(currentProduct)
         }
    }
   matches.forEach(function(match){
    $('#results').append("<ul><li>" + match.name + "</li><ul><li>Price : " + match.price + "</li><li>Quantity : " + match.quantity + "</li></ul></ul>");
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchForm">
  <input type="text" id="searchText" />
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>

<div id="results">

</div>
```

Did that answer your question ?
Hope it helped you !